# Cannot execute query because datetime won't be converted to string c#/MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor

I have this attempt to execute a query:

```
 hmrSingle = dbMngr.Set<HistoryMessagesRequested>().Where(x => x.dateregistration == msgv.DtRicezione && x.val == msgv.value && x.parameter == dmf.Description && x.DeviceID == ms.IDDevice).FirstOrDefault();
```

`dateregistration` and `DtRicezione` are both declared as `DateTime?` into the database context and they're "datetime" into MSSQL tables too.

I can't figure out why this problem is continuously present.

Comment: what is `msgv.DtRicezione` declared as? what is the actual *exact error message* that comes up here?

Comment: @MarcGravell as DateTime?, I specified before. Didn't I?

The exact error message is: "Conversion failed while converting a character string to a date or time."

But it has no sense: the two attribute (dateregistration and DtRicezione) are both declared as "DateTime?"...

Comment: Either your c# code has the property as string but your database column is datetime or your code is datetime but your database column is string. Consider editing your question and adding the table definition.

Comment: I agree that indeed sounds odd; can you tell us about the other properties? are any of those datetime too? `x.val`, `msg.value`, `x.parameter`, `dmf.Description`, `x.DeviceID`, `ms.IDDevice`, etc? There's definitely a string somewhere, but: we can see even less than you can...

Comment: None of them are datetime, only the two mentioned at the beginning

Comment: @bradbury9 they're all set as datetime type

Answer (score 1):

Any time you are using a nullable value type you need to use .value to get its value. Try:

```
hmrSingle = dbMngr.Set<HistoryMessagesRequested>().Where(x => x.dateregistration.value == msgv.DtRicezione.value && x.val == msgv.value && x.parameter == dmf.Description && x.DeviceID == ms.IDDevice).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: "Any time you are using a nullable value type you need to use .value to get its value." - that is not my experience at all - most ORMs deal with the "lifted operators" perfectly correctly (including when one or both value(s) is(/are) null)